# Error in Java or Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, noclassdeffounderror

This may take a bit to understand but I'll try and make it as straightforward as possible. I have the following projects in Netbeans (names changed to protect the innocent):

1. Core
2. Component1
3. Component2
4. Thinger

Both Component1, Component2 and Thinger require Core and so include a link to that project in their libraries.

Thinger also requires Component1.

Component1 also requires Component2.

Each of the projects compiles on their own (with just the references). However as soon as I create an instance of Component2 inside of Component1 I get the following error at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: somepackage.stuff/Component2
```

Keeping in mind that all of the projects continue to build just fine I am stumped. I am not using reflection and this only happens when I include the Component2 someVar = new Component2() line within Component1. Any idea what could be causing this to happen?

**UPDATE #1:** It doesn't seem to be pulling in Component2's jar while building Thinger. Is there a way I can force Netbeans to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a dependency to Component2 in Thinger. Many times components will have dependencies that aren't necessarily require for runtime (could be optional functionality, for example), but only for building. So, simply add the extra dependency to Thinger and it will be all good.